# How to reduce a React.js component's size when creating it from a higher level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, html5-canvas

I am using an html canvas in React.js to draw a picture.

I get the dimensions (in millimeters) for rectangles and paths through an api call.

Rather than passing down scaling variables to reduce the dimensions before drawing the canvas, I would like to draw the canvas assuming the dimensions are in pixels, and to then, when the component is created through a higher level call, reduce its size (i.e. scale it down to a fixed width, BUT keep the aspect ratio).

How can I do this?

Below some code to demonstrate. I use `withStyles` also, but I've excluded this from the sample code for the sake of brevity.

I have a CanvasComponent class:

```
import React from 'react'

class CanvasComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.updateCanvas();
    }
    updateCanvas() {
        const {drawing_objects, drawing, classes} = this.props
        const w = drawing.dims[0]
        const h = drawing.dims[1]
        const ctx = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = "#79d279"
        ctx.fillRect(0,0, w, h);

        let i;
        let r;
        for (i = 0; i < drawing_objects.length; i++) {
            r = drawing_objects[i]
            ctx.beginPath();
            ...
        }

    }
    render() {
        const {drawing_objects, drawing, classes} = this.props
        const w = drawing.dims[0]
        const h = drawing.dims[1]
        return (
            <canvas ref="canvas" width={w} height={h}/>
        );
    }
}

export default CanvasComponent
```

And when I create it from a higher level, I do something like:

```
import React from 'react'
import CanvasComponent from "../components/CanvasComponent"

class Index extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const {drawing, drawing_objects} = this.props
        return 
          <div >
              <CanvasComponent
              drawing={drawing}
              drawing_objects={drawing_objects}
              />
          </div> 
      }
  }
```